# How to select * and group by one column while selecting max of another column?

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
fruitID|fruitName     |dateAge
23     |Rotten Apple  |2
23     |Old Apple     |3 
23     |New Apple     |4
12     |Rotten Banana |4
12     |Old Banana    |5
12     |New Banana    |6
8      |New Mango     |6
7      |Rotten Grapes |5

expected result:

fruitID|fruitName     |dateAge
23     |New Apple     |4
12     |New Banana    |6
8      |New Mango     |6
7      |Rotten Grapes |5
```

I want the result to have the fruitID that has the latest harvest date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.fruitID, max(a.dateHarvest ) as dt, 
(select fruitName from test b where a.fruitID=b.fruitID and b.dateHarvest=max(a.dateHarvest )) 
as name from test a
group by a.fruitID
order by fruitID desc
```

Should do the trick (tablew name is test)

Edit : If you use group by, you cannot use *.

It's 2008R2, not 2012R2
[image]

Comment: It returned everything in the record :(

Comment: it still returned everything

Comment: I'm trying to recreate your database, but the date of 2016-2-31 can not exist :)